# how can i delete the vertices and Edges inside a mesh

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges, remesh

how can i delete the vertices and Edges inside a mesh? the problem can be fixed by Remesh, but unfortunately the visible faces are also rearranged. Which doesn't look nice. There should be a simple way to delete the vertices and edges within a mesh. how can i do that?[image]

Comment: Could you have used the same solution [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/286301/111042) to separate loose parts into separate objects that can be deleted for the cleanup?  Or are interior and exterior all connected by edges?

Comment: Thanks James, unfortunately this does not work. The picture below is just a simple example, which can be solved perfectly with Boolean. But for very complex objects, like at the very top of the image, this does not work. The Remesh modifier removes all the "innards" but destroys the topology on the surface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the *Select > Select All by Trait > Interior Faces* will work.

You can try the *Mesh: 3D-Print Toolbox* addon, activate it, then select your object in *Object* mode, in the *N panel > 3D Print*, click on *Check All*, then switch to *Edit* mode, click on *Non Manifold Edges* and remove the selected vertices with <kbd>X</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: @ Moonboots, thanks. unfortunately both of them does'nt help. It does not recognize the vertices and edges inside a mesh. The only thing that really helps is to solve this with the Remesh modifier. Unfortunately, the mesh then looks very unattractive, since it reshapes all visible faces. Which is not what I want in any case.

Comment: it does recognize non-manifold edges, but not vertices

Comment: too bad, I just see that this question has already been asked a few times, but unfortunately it can never be answered. There should be a tool that can delete the invisible things inside a mesh. With Boolean-Union this is possible for example, with two simple meshes, remove the "innards". For complex objects this seems to be wishful thinking. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: again, do you have lost vertices inside your mesh? If you have only edges, 3-Print Tools will work

Answer (score -1):

It worked, even if it is a bit complicated. I have to select and delete all vertices that are inside a mesh. The problem afterwards is that there are holes on the intersections. Is there also a solution for this?[image]

Comment: your first question was not clear, in the case you are showing, why don't you use the Face > Intersect (Boolean)?

Comment: @moonboots: The image with the cube and the sphere is just an example image, where I would of course use Boolean. But the image at the top is just a single object. My problem is that I have created figures that are very complex, or heavily edited. I like these figures very much from the outside view, but I want to "wireframe" them. Unfortunately I find that the figures are full of Edges/Faces/Vertices inside the figure, which I am trying to get rid of. I can't find an ideal solution for this so far. Remesh Voxel, removes the "waste" inside the mesh, but breaks the topology outside.